# Intune android sdk(with MSAL),Getting NPE at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.BrowserSelector.isFullBrowser(BrowserSelector.java:236)

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal, intune, intunemam, msal

I am integrating Intune SDK(with MSAL) on my android application. I am able to login via MSAL and am also seeing the Microsoft Intune's consent screen where i have to specify the pin. After both these steps application crashes with the exception trace below. I am using the latest Intune SDK for android and android api version is 33.Due to this i am not getting ENROLLMENT_SUCCEEDED intune notification at the end

````
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.BrowserSelector.isFullBrowser(BrowserSelector.java:236)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.BrowserSelector.getBrowsers(BrowserSelector.java:199)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.BrowserSelector.getDefaultBrowser(BrowserSelector.java:144)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.BrowserSelector.select(BrowserSelector.java:79)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by setting  "authorization_user_agent" : "WEBVIEW". Earlier it was set to "DEFAULT